# How to detect protected mode in a Volume Boot Record (Partition Boot Sector)?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, x86-16, boot

I am debugging an unusual booting arrangement in MBR mode (no EFI) on an x86 PC.
`IPL` in MBR --> exotic `BootManager`* --> `Partiton Boot Sector` --> experimental `OS`

I wrote a primitive 512-byte Partition Boot Sector (PBR) in 16-bit real mode `x86` assembly, which uses the `int 10h` BIOS services to display the 16-bit registers which are passed to it.  It works well for debugging.

I would like to enhance my debug PBR to also display info about the CPU mode, i.e. whether the BootManager has already switched the CPU into the [Protected Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode) (32bit or 64bit) or its submode such as the [Virtual 8086 mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_8086_mode). I need this info for debugging purposes.

How to reliably detect the `CPU mode` (and its subtype) in this scenario ?

- *The BootManger is located in the sectors between the MBR and the 1st partition and it intercepts/emulates BIOS services/interrupts - I have seen it pointing the `int 13h` vector to itself in a debugger*

*EDIT:  This question is NOT about detecting the CPU mode of a CPU emulated in software. (a.k.a.: virtual CPU)

Also, `Virtual CPU` is not the same as the `Virtual 8086 mode` of a real CPU.  The [Virtual 8086 mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_8086_mode) is a CPU mode, which is a submode of the [Protected Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode) and it is implemented in HARDWARE so the detection of this submode IS the subject of this question, together with the detection of the 32-bit and 64-bit [protected modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode), etc... implemented on real silicon*.

Comment: So you want to write machine code that will work correctly if executed in 16 or 32-bit mode?  Perhaps `mov ax, sp` / `push imm8` / `sub ax, sp` to see how much SP changes?  **Do `int 10h` BIOS services even work in 32-bit protected mode?**  See also this x86 polyglot machine code that detects 16 / 32 / 64-bit mode: [Determine your language's version](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139717) (optimized for code-size but well commented).  You could also read the relevant control register to see if the protected-mode bit has been set, to detect 16-bit protected vs. 16-bit real mode I guess.

Comment: Basically yes, but `mov eax,cr0` might cause an exception.  I also have to be ready to detect a 64bit protected mode.  The BIOS interrupts work because the BootManager intercepts or emulates them somehow.

Comment: *`mov eax,cr0` might cause an exception*  Only if the privilege level is 1 or higher (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov-1).  A bootloader can't really do its job if executed with privilege level aka ring 3, or really anything other than 0 (full kernel mode so it can run privileged instructions.)  So you might want to check and print current default operand-size with polyglot machine code, then read CR0 and print based on that.  If somehow you're not in ring 0 and you crash, then you'll only see the 16 / 32 / 64-bit output and know that checking CR0 failed.

Comment: Note that instructions are decoded differently in 32 bit or 64 bit modes, so if you are in any of them, your code will not work.  It is very hard to write code that does something meaningful in more than one of them.  Anyway, you can always use `smsw` to access some bits of CR0 from unprivileged code, the PM bit being one of them.

Comment: @fuz   ...but is the detection of Virtual 8086 doable at all ?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson Sure.  [Apparently it's not even difficult](https://wiki.osdev.org/Virtual_8086_Mode#Detecting_v8086).  Seems like I was wrong before.

Comment: No boot manager is going to switch to 32-bit protected mode for no reason. No volume (partition) boot record work if it did. It might switch to Virtual 8086 mode, but this unlikely as it would prevent protected mode operating systems from booting.

Comment: @Ross Ridge:  Indeed, no sane boot manager would, but a buggy one might.  This mode discovery is for debugging purposes.

Comment: Switching into protected mode isn't something that happens by accident.

Comment: @Ross Ridge:  But it is something that happens out of malice or myopic design,

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Ross: Apparently you have never encountered malware, which monitors and modifies boot managers with the aid of various CPU modes, such as the "REboot" bootkit. Read about it here: http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/static/publications/14-hitbamsterdam-reboot.pdf

Comment: If all a malware infected bootsector wanted to do was prevent Windows from booting it wouldn't have to switch to protected mode to do so

Comment: @Ross. The "REboot" bootkit does not prevent Windows form booting - it controls the Windows boot process in malicious manner.  Anyway, why are you focusing on MS-Windows - the original post does not mention Windows at all.

Comment: You can use `smsw ax` and check the low bit like `test al, 1`. If the mode is Virtual 86 Mode (eg, when booting in dosemu) then the low bit is set. In the case of Real 86 Mode the bit is clear.

Answer (score 2):

For guarding against simple rootkits, it's easy to check if you're in virtual8086 mode (as mentioned in ecm's comment - e.g. `smsw ax` and see if low bit is set).

This won't solve anything.

The problem is that a slightly more advanced rootkit will just use hardware virtualization instead (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_(software) ) so your simple test will pass.

To detect if you're in a virtualized environment you need to exploit weaknesses in the emulation (e.g. detect things that behave slightly differently than they should); but that's not easy if you have no idea what the weaknesses might be, and any weakness can be corrected in the next version of the rootkit until there are no weaknesses.

In other words; the entire approach can't be "guaranteed successful". Instead, you need a different approach.

The alternative approaches are "measuring" the code that was executed during boot (so you know if it was tampered with/altered because you end up with a different result of measuring after boot), and preventing unauthorized code from being executed in the first place.

For "measuring"; it's mostly just a glorified secure hash done by special hardware (e.g. TPM chip). This comes in 2 flavors - "static root of trust" (a measurement of everything executed during boot, including firmware, MBR, etc), and "dynamic root of trust" (resetting the CPUs to a known state later in boot, then measuring everything from that known state).

For preventing unauthorized code from being executed the most well known/well supported implementation is (UEFI) SecureBoot. The basic idea is to use digital signatures (where a secure hash of the executable file is encrypted by the publisher's private key; so that the signature can be checked by decrypting the signature with the publisher's public key and comparing it to a hash of the executable file). This allows modification to be detected (hash is wrong), and allows the publisher to be identified and authorized (if publisher's public key is not in a white-list of accepted publishers, or is in a black-list of denied publishers, then the system refuses to execute the code).

Comment: I agree with you about the futility of detecting the CPU mode with code executed by a deceptive software-virtualized CPU. However, the Original Question did not ask about detecting the CPU mode of a software virtualized CPU, so respectfully I cannot accept your answer. I think you became confused by the mention of a "Virtual 8086 mode" which is a CPU mode implemented in **HARDWARE** not software!!!. I will edit the question to specifically exclude the extreme case of CPU hardware virtualization performed by software, which you have focused on

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson: The first paragraph answers the question you asked (detect v8086 mode).  The rest of the answer is based on usual(?) reasons for wanting to detect v8086 in a bootloader: to detect a rootkit that might aim to run "outside" the OS, with the normal OS as a guest.  If that doesn't interest you, stop reading after the `smsw ax` part.  (You can safely assume that you're not in 32-bit protected mode, unless a previous boot sector had a huge bug.  There's no expectation that a bootloader should work if jumped to in protected mode.)